# JSP page not rendering with Spring Boot in Spring Tool Suite IDE

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-boot

I ended up getting this log as a result of running my Spring Boot App with a jsp.

```
2017-12-29 13:30:52.412  WARN 12631 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] 
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound              No mapping found for HTTP         
request with URI [/SpringBootTrial/] in DispatcherServlet with name
'dispatcherServlet'
2017-12-29 13:30:56.463  WARN 12631 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound              No mapping found for HTTP
request with URI [/SpringBootTrial/display] in DispatcherServlet with
name 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-12-29 13:30:56.464 ERROR 12631 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error
page for request [/welcome] as the response has already been
committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.
If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may
be able to resolve this problem by setting
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

It's evident that in Spring Boot, manual configuration is not needed. So, how should I fix this error?

I am clueless how to fix. I configured the jsp resolver in application.properties.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I have tomcat-embedded-jasper in the pom.xml.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Where is your JSP placed?